# Find all other zeros of P(x).

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$P(x) = 4x^4 − 9x^3 − 50x^2 − 27x + 10, \quad c = \frac {1}{4}, −2$$

So what I did was take the divisors of 4 and put it over the divisors of 10:

$\frac {1, 2, 4}{1,2,5,10}$ (positives and negatives)

Then I plugged in the original function $P(x)$ in my graphing calculator and used the table to find where $x=0$.

I got zeroes/roots at $-2, -1, \frac{1}{4}$. Did I miss something?

Comment: You missed 5. Checkout [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4x4%E2%88%929x3%E2%88%9250x2%E2%88%9227x%2B10).

Comment: it's divisors of $10$ over divisors of $4$; you're missing $x=5$

Comment: If in doubt, try to perform division of $P(x)$ by the known factors. For general case, there could be multiple roots, non-rational or even complex roots.

Comment: Since you're given some roots to begin with, I think your teacher/textbook probably intends for you to do it the way @peterwhy suggested.

Comment: Thank you guys, the missing roots were 5 and -1 :)